# Как получить значение числа inf?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Учусь в университете на первом курсе, и преподаватель дал задание - выяснить число, коим является "inf". Тоесть, вот сам код:

```
#include <iostream>

#define INFINITY

using namespace std;

void main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    double z = 5;

    z /= 0;

    cout << z ;
}
```

В консоль выводится "inf" [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Нужно получить это число, коим является "inf"

Comment: Что значит «выяснить число»? inf это и есть значение числа, получающееся после деления на ноль

Comment: @andreymal Как он сказал, есть три числа: -inf, inf, и nan, которые были известны ещё в 70-х. Тоесть, inf, -inf, и nan - это какие-то числа, при пяовлении которых программа будет выдавать строку "inf", ну или "nan" соответственно

Comment: inf, -inf и nan это есть конкретные значения float и double, ничего «выяснять» тут не надо

Comment: С этим к Земфире, это она разгадала знак бесконечность.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите описание форматов хранения чисел с плавающей точкой.

[Вот для float](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8), остальное сами

```
7f80 0000 = infinity
ff80 0000 = −infinity
```

Comment: Ссылка на [IEEE-754](https://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/IEEE-754references.html)

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать что-то подобное, только в правильности порядка выводимого числа не уверен. Оно просто выводит значения байтов с конца.

```
#include <iostream>
#define INFINITY
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double z = 5;
    z /= 0;
    cout<<z<<endl;
    unsigned char *test;
    test =(unsigned char*) &z;
    int max_adr=sizeof(double);
    for(int i=max_adr-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        cout <<hex<<(int)*(test+i) ;

    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```